# How can I get selected rows on Devexpress MVC GridView?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want to get rows which selected on Devexpress MVC GridView at a time. Not at each item clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reference:** [How to get all GridView selected keys and pass them to a Controller](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E20065)

> You can collect all selected values (for example, keys) on the client
>   side via the [ASPxClientGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) method and
>   pass them to:
>
> - The GridView callback action via the e.customArgs dictionary ([Passing Values to Controller Action Through Callbacks](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9941));
> - Any controller post action via a hidden input element.

Example code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedIDs;
    function OnBeginCallback(s, e) {
        //Pass all selected keys to GridView callback action
        e.customArgs["selectedIDs"] = selectedIDs;
    }
    function OnSelectionChanged(s, e) {
        s.GetSelectedFieldValues("PersonID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
    }
    function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
        //Capture all selected keys
        selectedIDs = "";
        for (var index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            selectedIDs += values[index] + ",";
        }
        if (selectedIDs.length > 0)
            selectedIDs = selectedIDs.substring(0, selectedIDs.length - 1);
    }
    function OnClick(s, e) {
        //Show all selected keys on client side
        alert(selectedIDs);
    }
    function OnSubmitClick(s, e) {
        //Write all selected keys to hidden input. Pass them on post action.
        $("#selectedIDsHF").val(selectedIDs);
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
namespace Sample.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        PersonsList list = new PersonsList();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View(list.GetPersons());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string selectedIDsHF) {
            //Get all selected keys from hidden input
            string _selectedIDs = selectedIDsHF;

            return View(list.GetPersons());
        }

        public ActionResult GridViewEditingPartial() {
            //Get all selected keys from e.customArgs on GridView callback
            string _selectedIDs = Request.Params["selectedIDs"];
            ViewData["_selectedIDs"] = _selectedIDs;

            return PartialView(list.GetPersons());
        }

    }
}
```

Note: The client-side [GetSelectedKeysOnPage Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedKeysOnPagetopic) returns key values of selected rows displayed within the current page.

References:
[GridView - How to get selected rows as an action parameter](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q367172)
[GridView - How to get values of selected rows in the Controller's Action](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q320587)
[How do I get my selected GridView rows into a Javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124809/how-do-i-get-my-selected-gridview-rows-into-a-javascript-variable)
[DevExpress MVC GridView - How to get cell click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848543/devexpress-mvc-gridview-how-to-get-cell-click-event)
[How to highlight a particular row in a page of a DevExpress MVC GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875641/how-to-highlight-a-particular-row-in-a-page-of-a-devexpress-mvc-gridview)